# Hadoop-Apache Ranger: StackOverflowError on namenode restart

Tags: hadoop, apache-ranger

I am getting [this error](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/5qmVmTwJyY/) after enabling hdfs plugin in apache ranger.
When I run `enable-hdfs-plugin.sh` ranger adds following configuration in `hdfs-site.xml`.

```
<property>
      <name>dfs.permissions.enabled</name>
      <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>dfs.permissions</name>
      <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.inode.attributes.provider.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.ranger.authorization.hadoop.RangerHdfsAuthorizer</value>
  </property>
```

But if I remove the above property and restart my namenode, it starts with no error. Also, when I try to format the namenode it gives me the same error.

[This](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/9ZpSK22nsD/) is my `install.properties` of ranger's hdfs-plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Link `ranger-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-hdfs-plugin/lib/ranger-hdfs-plugin-impl` to `/var/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/ranger-hdfs-plugin-impl`
2. Link `ranger-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-hdfs-plugin/lib/ranger-hdfs-plugin-shim-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` to `/var/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/ranger-hdfs-plugin-shim-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`
3. Link `ranger-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-hdfs-plugin/lib/ranger-plugin-classloader-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` to `/var/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/ranger-plugin-classloader-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

follow these instruction as per your file path. The problem is due to classloader is not found in your hadoop file path.